# Personal Visit on Business Visa Type C

Tags: visas, uk, business-travel

I have been ussued the Business visa type C, multiple entry, valid for 2 years. I got it issued in Jan 2019, sponsored by my company for business purposes.

But I have not travelled on any business meetings yet. However, I'd like to visit my friends and relatives in the UK for a week or so.

Can I do a personal travel on a business visa? Also, what documents will I have to provide at Immigration for this?

Please let me know. Thanks in advance !

Shruthi

P.S. I see that a lot of places mention standard visit visa, but my visa clearly stayes business visa, type C visit.

Comment: It's the same visa, you're fine to use it to travel for tourist/visit reasons, obviously it doesn't guarantee you entry, thats down to the immigration officer.

Comment: The UK hasn’t issued Business Visas for several years, the relevant visa type is a Standard Visitor visa which allows the holder to carry out the business-related activities permitted under the Visitor Rules https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa A Standard Visitor visa is normally valid for 6 months unless you’ve demonstrated that you have a good reason for needing to visit the UK regularly over a longer period. For clarity, are you saying you have been issued with a long-term Standard Visitor Visa valid for 2 years?

Comment: You have created multiple accounts ([Shruthi](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/93651/shruthi) and [Shruthi](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/93652/shruthi)).  You can [merge them](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 1):

Permitted business-related activities are covered under the UK’s Standard Visitor visa type https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa

Bring the same documents you’d need to apply for a visa, to show to officers at the UK border, if asked. https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf